# Open Matlab file .mat with module PICKLE in Python

Tags: python, matlab, pickle

I want open a **Matlab** project with the module **Pickle** or **cPickle** in **Python language**.
NOT with:

```
from scipy.io import matlab
mat=matlab.loadmat('file.mat')
```

Can I use `pickle.load` with a .mat file?

Comment: short answer: you can't, they are completely different formats, keep using SciPy...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As everybody else already mentions: it can't be done as the format is different.

Comment: Sounds like trying to open a lock with the wrong key, and complaining that the door doesn't open. Different datatypes require different libraries or programs to open them, that's life.

Answer (score 4):

For some years now, Matlab has used HDF5 to store data.  Python has support for HDF5, via `PyTables`.  No need to use Pickle.  In fact, HDF5 may surprise you for its speed relative to Pickle.  A friend reported 2-10X speedups in read/write for some very large datasets.

---

Update 1: A concise guide to loading the files, via HDF5, can be found [at this page](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Reading_mat_files).

In addition, several good references and resources may be found [at this page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/290116).  There's also a [PyMat project on Sourceforge](http://pymat.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `Pickle` loads Python objects that have been serialized to binary data. The format is nothing like the Matlab file format.

If you have read all the data you need out of the matlab file and stored it in Python objects, you can then store it for later use by Pickling it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. From the pickle [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

> The pickle module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for
>   serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling”
>   is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a
>   byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte
>   stream is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and
>   unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,”
>   [1](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or “flattening”, however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here
>   are “pickling” and “unpickling”.

In your case you could load the *.mat object with scipy.io and then serializing it in some python structure that you may define. At that point you will be able to easily pickle and unpickle it. (but this last step depends, and in some use case it is not worth to be done).